# What is the syntax for increasing the size of a BLOB datatype in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

Docs say :

```
ALTER TABLE <table name>

ADD (<lobcol> <LOBTYPE> <LOB_clause_same_as_for_create>) |

MODIFY LOB (<lobcol>) (

            [PCTVERSION <version_number>]

            [ { CACHE | NO CACHE [{LOGGING | NOLOGGING}]

                      | CACHE READS [{LOGGING | NOLOGGING}]

              }

            ]

) |

MOVE [ONLINE] [<physical_attributes>] [TABLESPACE <tablespace_name>]

[LOGGING | NOLOGGING] [<LOB_clause_same_as_for_create>]
```

With an example of:

```
ALTER TABLE test_lob

MODIFY LOB (image) (

    STORAGE (NEXT 1M)

    CACHE

);
```

I tried this with my table and column names:

```
ALTER TABLE  <table name>

MODIFY LOB (<column name>) (

    STORAGE (NEXT 10M)

);
```

But I get an ORA-25150 ALTERING of extent parameters not permitted error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  Your question title indicates that you're trying to increase the size of a `BLOB`-- that is neither possible nor necessary...  A `BLOB` will always allow you to store at least many GB of data (almost certainly much more depending on the exact Oracle version and your block size).  The code you posted appears to be trying to change the extent size of the `BLOB` which is a very different thing.  Are you using locally managed tablespaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

table name is missing from your code

```
ALTER TABLE

MODIFY LOB (<column name>) (
STORAGE (NEXT 10M)

);
```

should be

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME
MODIFY LOB (<column name>) (

STORAGE (NEXT 10M)

);
```

Comment: Yeah, I formatted the code wrong in the question post...it has been corrected.  Thank you for the response.