# Error while uploading image to database

Tags: image, exception, file-upload, jdbc, upload

When I am trying to upload an Image using below code, I am getting following error : **java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested**

```java
    File image = new File("D:/"+fileName);      
    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
    preparedStatement.setString(1,"Ayush");   
    fis = new FileInputStream(image);
    preparedStatement.setBinaryStream(2, (InputStream)fis, (int)(image.length()));

    int s = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    if(s>0) {
        System.out.println("Uploaded successfully !");
        flag = true;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("unsucessfull to upload image.");
        flag = false;
    }
```

Please help me out.

DB Script : 
**CREATE TABLE ESTMT_SAVE_IMAGE
  (
    NAME VARCHAR2(50),
    IMAGE BLOB
  )**

Comment: For several users, this was solved by getting the latest jdbc driver.
See these links:
http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=1808509 and
http://forum.java.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5164500&tstart=255

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its first cause is incompatible conversion but after seeing your DB script, I assume that you are not doing any conversion in your script.
There are other reported causes of the ORA-01460 as well:

*Incompatible character sets can cause an ORA-01460*

*Using SQL Developer, attempting to pass a string to a bind variable value in excess of 4000 bytes can result in an ORA-01460*

*With ODP, users moving from the 10.2 client and 10.2 ODP to the 11.1 client and 11.1.0.6.10 ODP reported an ORA-01460 error.  This was a bug that should be fixed by patching ODP to the most recent version.*

[Please see this](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01460_unimplemented_or_unreasonable_conversion_requested.htm)

Comment: Yes you are right. My application is successfully inserting image of size less than 4KB to database but what if I want to store a larger size image?

Comment: as I am not much expert :) but I think you need to store is as a binary data.

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10176754/what-is-the-syntax-for-increasing-the-size-of-a-blob-datatype-in-oracle and http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A91202_01/901_doc/appdev.901/a88879/adl06fa8.htm I am damn sure that it will help you :)